# OpenWRT/DD-WRT/Tomato-compatible wifi repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, tomato, openwrt, repeater

I'd like to set up a wifi box to act as a repeater to pick up the somewhat weak signal of a friend's wifi router and make it available at my place.

Ideally, I'd rather buy a device that supports the three main open-source alternative firmwares OpenWrt, DD-Wrt, and Tomato, so I can experiment and choose the one that works best for this need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linksys WRT54G WiFi Repeater**

**Unleash the Hidden Features Using DD-WRT**

**Overview**

Linksys WRT54G router is capable of working in repeater mode with third party firmware like DD-WRT. A WiFi repeater is a device that will connect to another wireless access point and redistribute the signal. Repeaters are typically used to extend the coverage of a network in office buildings, hotels, convention halls, airports and other public spaces.

Repeaters can also be used on a smaller scale to share an internet connection with a neighbor. You can also use a repeater to set up a communal open hotspot and share the connection with a group of neighbors.

**Installing DD-WRT**

As of June 2007, DD-WRT beta v24 firmware is the only version that works in repeater mode. You can download it [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/).

To determine which one is appropriate for your version of WRT54G you need to consult the [wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices). Some of the more recent versions of WRT54G have a RAM issue that can be overcome by installing the smaller "micro" version.

DD-WRT firmware is relatively easy to install and setup. The installation process varies slightly based on the version of the router you have. The older WRT54G models you can buy used on Ebay are better candidates for third party firmware installation.

Linksys has moved away from open source firmware in the new models of WRT54G. However, the current WRT54GL will still accept third party firmware. Not surprisingly, this model costs more than comparable units so stick to the used stuff when you can.

[Source](http://www.skifactz.com/wifi/wrt54g_repeater.htm)

**[Tutorial](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3655041)**

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. If possible, I'd like something more recent than the WRT54 series and with more RAM.

Comment: more RAM? ^^ 2048 MB RAM enough? then setup an Aspire REVO with an additional USB WLAN controller as repeater, costs like 220 dollar.

Comment: Seems like Linksys, Asus, and Buffalo are the most recommended brands, with some models having enough RAM to run the apps I need. Thanks for the idea for the Revo.

Comment: @overtherainbow: actually, WRT54GL has more memory than the WRT54G, and I think the GS even has more (not sure if that one is still flash-able though).

Comment: or use some old netbook, i bought 1 701 2G with a broken display for a tenner, add to that a USB Wifi adapter with a decent arial (think DIY) and it should be cheaper than a new router/repeater.

Comment: Right, but I prefer a compact, silent box.

Comment: if you get a 701, it's no bigger in size than your average home router and since you're doing nothing demanding, you might as well disconnect the fan (at your own risk, of course. but the 2G's throttled Celeron at 571 MHz doesn't really require cooling).

Comment: This is a very old thread. Would be great to see a current answer, for current hardware.